# Is Apache Curator performant?

Tags: mpi, distributed-computing, apache-zookeeper, distributed-system, apache-curator

I have a high-level idea of what Curator and Zookeeper do. However, I don’t know whether they manage information in-memory or on disk. For example, the “receipes” for barrier or distributed queue suggest to open a node (node is a file?) at specific paths; are these nodes maintained in-memory or are they files on disk / HDFS? I think traditional barriers across machines now need to be done via Curator barrier; hence, won’t these operations be slow if they involve heavy operations?

How does the Curator barrier compare with traditional MPI barrier in terms of performance?

Answer (score 3):

ZooKeeper is a quorum based, single leader system and so, while it does hold state in memory, it is limited by the throughput that can be sustained by the leader. All state changes in ZooKeeper go through the leader and are synchronously replicated to and persisted on a majority of nodes, but reads can be made on any node.

In ZooKeeper, a node (or znode) refers to a piece of state that is held in memory and backed by disk. It uses a file-like interface, but znodes do not map to individual files. Disk does not mean HDFS, it essentially means a commit log.

What you're getting by using ZooKeeper for locks or barriers is linearizability. The cost of consistency is relatively high because of the constraints of consensus (quorums). But ZooKeeper has a great event notification system that helps with performance for things like locks and barriers.